# Seamless HTML5 Looping of a video

Tags: html, video

I haven't been able to find a solution to this and the questions (and answers) on Stackoverflow don't provide a solution to this.

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" id="hero" autoplay loop preload="auto">
  <source src="video/forwomen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/forwomen.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I want my video to loop *seamlessly* and every time it loops, there is a period where the video is paused at the beginning. Is there a way to get rid of that awkward pause?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?